# QVBoxLayout is Undeclared Identifier

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I am developing a simple application using Qt Framework and C++ and currently I am stuck because of `Undeclared Identifier` errors.

I included these libraries:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QFrame>
```

And here is the declerations of `QVBoxLayout` and `QHBoxLayout`:

```
QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout(this);
QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout();
vbox->addStretch(1);
widget = new Widget(this);
hbox->addWidget(widget, 0);
vbox->addLayout(hbox);
setLayout(vbox);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try #include <QVBoxLayout>

Comment: But <QVBoxLayout> is just an alias to QBoxLayount and QtGui already includes QBoxLayout

Comment: Including QVBoxLayout makes errors dissapear. Thank you.

Comment: @BeniBela: QVBoxLayout is a subclass of QBoxLayout for sure, but it's not included by default with QtGUI. Not as far as I can remember.

Comment: @NicholasSmith: I  checked the header, it is included in line 16. (qt4.8.5)

Comment: @ciyo: Don't use the `QtGui` header, it's not portable to Qt 5, and in any case why pull everything in? You're supposed to `#include <QClassName>`, for every class you use. Can't get any simpler than that.

Comment: @BeniBela: weird, everytime I've used a V/HBoxLayout I've always needed to include the header specifically for either of them.